# How to get the previous deployment details of my app on Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I need to find the past deployment details(TimeStamp) of my application running on Cloud Foundry.

Does anyone know where I can find this? I am looking into the API documentation(https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/236/) but not able to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `cf events APP_NAME` give you what you need?

Comment: Thanks a lot Amit. cf events helped me to get the recent app deployment information. But I wonder if it has a time restriction, because I am unable to see the information beyond a certain date. Does it depend on some configuration on my side.

Comment: If you're deploying Cloud Foundry yourself (or someone in your organization is deploying it for you), then yes, the app event retention periods can be configured: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/capi-release/blob/master/jobs/cloud_controller_ng/spec#L132-L149.